# Microsoft SQL gradually increasing RAM consumption while using my website

Tags: sql-server, memory, memory-leak

I'm developing a website hosted on Apache 8.5 that connects to a Microsoft SQL server using Hybernate and the entity/dao/bean structure.

When I start the server where MS SQL is located and open the Task Manager, I can see it's consuming around 500 Mb of RAM. Then I start using my website (which is already accessed by some company clients), which is closed and reopen frequently, and what happens is that the RAM consumption of MS SQL server starts growing (Apache itself remains fine). This happens until a Java Heap Space error occurrs and I have do restart the machine (actually a cloud server).

My question is: what could possibly be leading the SQL Server to gradually increase its RAM consumption?

If it was Apache facing that problem, I'ld suspect some memory leak was occurring even though my website is Java based and the Garbage Collector is supposed to have run a couple of times during the 3-4 days until JHS error occcurs. But it's not apache, it's SQL server itself! If by one had I don't have to put objects = null in my code because Java's GC will take care of freeing memory, do I need to implement something similar in the entity/dao/bean codes?

Here are examples of my codes concerning the database (note: some minor details cut out to reduce text size):

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BANDEIRAS", schema="dbo", catalog=Global.DATABASE_NAME
)
public class Bandeiras implements java.io.Serializable {

    private BigDecimal id;
    private String descricao;
    private Double valorKwh;

    public Bandeiras() {
    }

    public Bandeiras(BigDecimal id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Bandeiras(BigDecimal id, String descricao, Double valorKwh) {
        this.id = id;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.valorKwh = valorKwh;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public BigDecimal getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(BigDecimal id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "DESCRICAO", length = 30)
    public String getDescricao() {
        return this.descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    @Column(name = "VALOR_KWH", precision = 126, scale = 0)
    public Double getValorKwh() {
        return this.valorKwh;
    }

    public void setValorKwh(Double valorKwh) {
        this.valorKwh = valorKwh;
    }
}
```

Dao:

```
public class BandeirasDao implements Serializable {

    private Session session = null;
    private List<Bandeiras> list;

    public BandeirasDao() {
    }

    public List<Bandeiras> getListBandeiras() {
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

            session.beginTransaction();

            Criteria cri = session.createCriteria(Bandeiras.class);        
            this.list = cri.list();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (session.isOpen())
                session.close();
        }   

        return list;
    }

    public boolean edit(Bandeiras b) {
        boolean editado;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(b);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            editado = true;

            session.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            editado = false;

            if (session.isOpen())
                session.close();
        }
        return editado;
    }

    public boolean create(Bandeiras b) {
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(b);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            session.close();

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();

            if (session.isOpen())
                session.close();

            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean remove(Bandeiras b) {
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(b);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            session.close();

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();

            if (session.isOpen())
                session.close();

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bandBean")
@SessionScoped
public class BandeirasBean implements Serializable {

    private Bandeiras bandeira;
    private Bandeiras novaBandeira;
    private Bandeiras auxBandeira;
    private BandeirasDao bandeiraDao;
    private ArrayList<Bandeiras> ListBandeira;
    UsuariosBean usrBean;

    public Bandeiras getAuxBandeira() {
        return auxBandeira;
    }

    public void setAuxBandeira(Bandeiras auxBandeira) {
        this.auxBandeira = auxBandeira;
    }

    public BandeirasBean() {
        this.bandeira = new Bandeiras();
        this.novaBandeira = new Bandeiras();
        this.bandeiraDao = new BandeirasDao();
    }

    public Bandeiras getBandeira() {
        return bandeira;
    }

    public void setBandeira(Bandeiras b) {
        this.bandeira = b;
    }

    public Bandeiras getNovaBandeira() {
        return novaBandeira;
    }

    public void setNovaBandeira(Bandeiras nB) {
        this.novaBandeira = nB;
    }

    public BigDecimal getId() {
        return this.bandeira.getId();
    }

    public ArrayList<Bandeiras> getListBandeiras() {
        ListBandeira = null;
        ListBandeira = new ArrayList(this.bandeiraDao.getListBandeiras());
        return ListBandeira;
    }

    public ArrayList<SelectItem> getComboListTarifas(BigDecimal empr) {
        ArrayList<Bandeiras> tmp = getListBandeiras();
        ArrayList<SelectItem> itemCombo = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Bandeiras bd : tmp) {
            SelectItem si = new SelectItem();
            si.setLabel(bd.getDescricao());
            si.setValue(bd.getId());
            itemCombo.add(si);
        }

        return itemCombo;
    }

    public Bandeiras getDadosEditBandeiras() {
        return auxBandeira;
    }

    public void getBandeirasEdit(BigDecimal id) {
        auxBandeira = null;
        auxBandeira = new Bandeiras();

        getListBandeiras();

        for (Bandeiras b : ListBandeira) {
            if (b.getId().equals(id)) {
                auxBandeira = b;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void removeBandeira(BigDecimal id) {
        auxBandeira = null;
        auxBandeira = new Bandeiras();

        getListBandeiras();

        for (Bandeiras b : ListBandeira) {
            if (b.getId().equals(id)) {
                auxBandeira = b;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (this.bandeiraDao.remove(auxBandeira)) {
            String correctText = "Bandeira excluída com sucesso";

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                    "datatable_form:hiddenInput",
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                            correctText, ""));

            auxBandeira = null;
        } else {
            String correctText = "Erro na remoção da bandeira";

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                    null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
                            correctText, ""));

            auxBandeira = null;
        }
    }

    public void editBandeira(String hidden_info)
    {
        try{
            if(new BandeirasDao().edit(this.auxBandeira)){
                String correctText;

                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                        hidden_info,
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                        correctText, " "));
            }
            else{
                String correctText;

                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                        hidden_info,
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                        correctText, " "));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //this.auxBandeira = new Bandeiras();
        }    
        finally{
            //this.auxBandeira = new Bandeiras();
        }
    }

    public String criaTarifa(String page) {
        //BigDecimal emp = new BigDecimal(idEmp);
        //EmpresasDao eprsa = new EmpresasDao();
        //novaBandeira.setEmpresas(eprsa.getUser(emp));
        if (this.bandeiraDao.create(novaBandeira)) {
            String correctText;

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                    "datatable_form:hiddenInput",
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                            correctText, ""));
            novaBandeira = new Bandeiras();
            return page;
        } else {
            String correctText;

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                    null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
                            correctText, ""));
            novaBandeira = new Bandeiras();

            return page;
        }
    }

    public String editTarifa(Bandeiras b, String page) {
        if (this.bandeiraDao.edit(b)) {
            String correctText;

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                    "datatable_form:hiddenInput",
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                            correctText, ""));
            return page;
        } else {
            String correctText;

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                    null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
                            correctText, ""));
            return page;
        }
    }

    public UsuariosBean getUsrBean() {
        return usrBean;
    }

    public void setUsrBean(UsuariosBean usrBean) {
        this.usrBean = usrBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not configure maximum memory usage for SQL Server?

Answer (score 4):

This is a normal behaviour of MS SQL Server engine : it uses all the RAM that we allow it to consume for caching.

you can limit this by a simple configuration :

- connect to instance with SQL Management studio
- right click on instance name / **Properties**
- in **Memory** tab, you can set **maximum server memory** value to let enough memory for system and you application

Steps are detailed [here](https://www.javelin-tech.com/blog/2017/11/microsoft-sql-standard-memory-limit/)

Regards,

Comment: I would like to add, here are some guidelines for allocating to SQL given various amounts of overall system RAM.  If you have: 
8 GB total - 4GB for OS, 4GB for SQL
12 GB total - 4GB for OS, 8GB for SQL
16 GB total - 5GB for OS, 11GB for SQL
24 GB total - 6GB for OS, 18GB for SQL
32 GB total - 7GB for OS, 25GB for SQL
40 GB total - 8GB for OS, 32GB for SQL
Add 1GB for the OS for every 8GB of total RAM from this point forward.

More in-depth discussion can be found here: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/how-much-memory-does-my-sql-server-actually-need/